# before all" hook for "should allow a purchase" error - Chainshot

Tags: hardhat, events, alchemy

I am completing series of tutorials on chainshot. Now I am on events 4. - Sale and I am getting an error

> "before all" hook for "should allow a purchase"

and I don't have an idea how to fix it.

**Task:**
Create an event called Purchase which takes two arguments: a uint for the purchase amount, and an address for the buyer.
Create an external, payable function purchase which allows a buyer to purchase the collectible at the asking price.

To make this purchase happen you'll need to do 3 things:
Transfer the msg.value to the seller.
Transfer the ownership to the buyer.
Mark the collectible as not for sale any longer.

My code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Collectible 
{
    address owner;
    uint price;
    bool purchased = false;

    event Deployed(address _address);
    event Transfer(address owner, address newOwner);
    event ForSale(uint price, uint blockTimestamp);
    event Purchase(uint purchaseAmount, address buyerAddress);

    constructor()
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
        emit Deployed(msg.sender);
    }

    function transfer(address _recipient) external
    {
        if(msg.sender == owner)
        {
            emit Transfer(owner, _recipient);
            owner = _recipient;
        }
        else
        {
            revert();
        }
    }

    function markPrice(uint _askingPrice) external
    {
        if(msg.sender == owner)
        {
            emit ForSale(_askingPrice, block.timestamp);
            price = _askingPrice;
        }
        else
        {
            revert();
        }
    }

    function purchase() external payable
    {
        if(msg.value >= price && msg.value != 0 && purchased == false)
        {
            emit Purchase(msg.value, msg.sender);
            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
            price = 0;
            purchased = true;
        }
        else
        {
            revert();
        }

    }
}
```

console output:

```
Collectible
    ✔ should revert if a purchase is attempted before the item is marked for sale (100ms)
    after marking a price
      ✔ should revert if a purchase is attempted with less money than the price
    after purchasing
      ✔ should emit a Purchase event
      ✔ should pay the owner
      ✔ should fail on the next purchase attempt
      after marking a new price
        1) "before all" hook for "should allow a purchase"


  5 passing (478ms)
  1 failing

  1) Collectible
       after purchasing
         after marking a new price
           "before all" hook for "should allow a purchase":
     Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
    at Collectible.markPrice (contracts/collectible.sol:43)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (/usr/local/node-16.15.1/bin/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1815:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (/usr/local/node-16.15.1/bin/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:504:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (/usr/local/node-16.15.1/bin/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
```

I also have test.js file if it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in function purchase you need to update de owner by the new one  this is my version of function purchase `

```
    if(price!=msg.value || price==0 ){revert();} 
    payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
      emit Purchase(price ,msg.sender);
      owner=msg.sender;
      price=0;
`
```